# Mapping dictionary to dataframe with dict value being a list

Tags: python, pandas

Note: Pandas 23.4
I have a dictionary in which the my values are all in list format.

```
dct = {'A': ['1','2','3']}
```

And I want to map it to a dataframe

```
Letter 
  A
```

Expected output:

```
Letter    Numb
  A       ['1','2','3']
```

This should be straightforward but the standard `map` doesn't seem to work ??

```
df['Numb'] = df['Letter'].map(dct)
```

Comment: Can you provide your dictionary as an actual dictionary?

Comment: Just tested in `0.25.0` and it works. Your probably are having mismatches due to whitespaces or uppercase/lowercase. Try `df['Numb'] = df['Letter'].str.strip().map(dct)`

Comment: ps. Dont call your lists `list` or your dictionary's `dict`, these are reserved python words.

Comment: I may have figured it out, it seems that the data in the key column prior to creating the dict is preceded by a tab...annoying...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `Series`, then do `merge`

```
s=pd.Series(dct).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Letter'})
df=df.merge(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dictionary is :

```
dct = { 'A' : ['1','2','3']}
```

try

```
df=pd.DataFrame(dct)
```

and visualize it

```
print(df)
```

hope this helps, Giulio